# How do the two R codes, which should do the same thing (at least in my head), differ?

Tags: filter, rstudio

In order to replicate this code, you will need these packages: 
Tidyverse, Nycflights13

I am basically trying to understand why two pieces of code, which in my head should do the same thing, don't do the same thing.

I am currently learning R for data science from R for Data Science by Garrett Grolemund & Hadley Wickham, and I've gotten to a point which the code begins to confuse me quite a bit, which hopefully is normal! I will write down the two pieces of code which confuse me in why they don't do the same thing!

```
filter(flights, dest == c("HOU","IAH"))
#and
filter(flights, dest == "HOU" | dest == "IAH")
```

I expected both of these codes to show the same amount of rows but the first one shows 4658 rows (the wrong amount), where as the second one shows 9313 (the right amount).
What I wanted to do is to shorten the code by using (filter(flights, dest == c("HOU","IAH"))) instead of (filter(flights, dest == "HOU" | dest == "IAH"))
but it yields different results, which gravely confuses me!
Please give me your advice, I am a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `filter(flights, dest == c("HOU","IAH"))` is the same as

```
filter(flights, dest == c("HOU","IAH"))
flights$dest = c("HOU","IAH")
* # For demonstation purposes, I'm assuming the flights dataset has has 4 rows, as:
c("HOU","CPH","IAH","EDI") == c("HOU","IAH")
```

Now, a vector of 4 elements cannot possible be the same as a vector of 2 elements. And this performs an *element-wise* comparison, `"HOU" == "HOU", "CPH" == "IAH", "IAH" == ???`. So R "helps" us by repeating the shorter vector. The output is thus:

```
> c("HOU","CPH","IAH","EDI") == c("HOU","IAH")
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Try extending with a 5th element:

```
> c("HOU","CPH","IAH","EDI", "LDN") == c("HOU","IAH")
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

> Warning message:
>   In c("HOU", "CPH", "IAH", "EDI", "LDN") == c("HOU", "IAH") :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

and you broke it.

So the 1st line only makes sense *if and only if* `flights` has 2 rows, whereupon an element-wise comparison can be performed.

However, what you might be looking for is the `%in%` operator:

```
> c("HOU","CPH","IAH","EDI") %in% c("HOU","IAH")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> c("HOU","CPH","IAH","EDI","LDN") %in% c("HOU","IAH")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

which can be expanded to `filter(flights, dest %in% c("HOU","IAH"))` and luckily works for vectors of any length.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I wasn't expecting such a quick answer, thus I went and deleted the question after realising why it didn't work as I expected it to, but your answer is far more detailed than what I had in my head! Appreciate it,  MrGumble!